# SQL for pulling targeted data from a table

Tags: sql-server

friends.

Have a quick question.

I have a log table and I need to pull specific info from it.

There are lots of columns, include date/time stamp and some transaction codes.

Records are for multiple account numbers.

I would like to pull the following:

- Pull a couple of fields from the record (for each account number) with transaction code of 100.  There can be multiple records with this code.
- Find the first transaction with transcode 101 AFTER that 100 code record and include the timestamp from this record.

Any help, as always, will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Please share  table structures, column names and also for Q#2 , what do you mean by 'AFTER'. Does it mean the next timestamp?

Comment: Also what do you mean  by  'some transaction codes'? Are they part of rows or columns(flat table)? Could there be multiple rows with the same transaction code? If not, then any row with transaction_code automatically becomes the next record. Also what you mean by ' that 100 code record'?If there are multiple records with transaction code 100 then which record is the  record in question?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague. Please edit and add extra information on it. With whatever I understood so far, this is what I could come up with:

1. `SELECT AccountNumber, COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM YOURTABLE WHERE TRANSACTION_CODE = 100--NO AGGREGATION`
2. I am assuming that by 'after' you mean the next time stamp. In that case..

   `SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM YOURTABLE WHERE DATETIME_TSTAMP=(
   SELECT MIN(DATETIME_TSTAMP) FROM YOURTABLE WHERE DATETIME_TSTAMP > (  SELECT DATETIME_TSTAMP FROM YOURTABLE WHERE TRANSACTION_CODE = 100) AND TRANSACTION_CODE = 101)`

OR

```
   SELECT COL1, COL2, DATETIMESTAMP FROM (
SELECT COL1, COL2, DATETIMESTAMP, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) ROWNUM FROM YOURTABLE WHERE TRANSACTION_CODE =  101 AND DATETIMESTAMP >
(SELECT DATETIMESTAMP FROM YOURTABLE WHERE TRANSACTION_CODE = 100))A 
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Comment: Ok.. a bit more clarity:
Table has following columns.
AccountNumber(num10), Transcode(num3), DateStamp(DateTime)
There are almost always multiple trans 101s for each 100 instance of an account.

I want to get a result of account number for each record with a code of 100, along with the datestamp for that (100) record, as well as the datestamp of the first 101 transaction for that account which occurred AFTER the 100 transaction.